# How to plot a cosine wave in MATLAB given fitted parameters?

Tags: matlab, plot, trigonometry

In my project, I used a generic cosine function to fit my data:

```
cos_fun = @(p, theta) p(1) + p(2) * cos(theta - p(3))

p = nlinfit(x,y,cos_fun,[1 1 0])
```

As a result, `p` has three values, which are y-offset, amplitude and phase.

Can I draw a smooth cosine curve using these three parameters?

Comment: What about using nlintool?

Comment: @Daniel yes, `nlintool` works but requires a toolbox.  See my answer which includes this with and without the toolbox requirement.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** It is possible to both fit and plot the curve, with and without requiring toolboxes. All cases presented below.

---

## Plotting

Plotting the function follows directly from the function used to obtain your parameters using [`plot()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html). Notice that you control the *smoothness* of the plotted function based on the step size for the domain (see `step` below).

In the figure, the results obtained from the [`nlinfit()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) (**Toolbox required**) are the same as "SSE" obtained without a toolbox using [`fminsearch()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html).

[image: Plot comparing fitted functions to the data. No toolbox required.]

```
% Plot   (No toolbox Required)
step = 0.01;                  % smaller is smoother
Xrng = 0:step:12;

figure, hold on, box on
plot(Xdata,Ydata,'b.','DisplayName','Data')
plot(Xrng,cos_fun(p_SSE,Xrng),'r--','DisplayName','SSE')
plot(Xrng,cos_fun(p_SAE,Xrng),'k--','DisplayName','SAE')
legend('show')
```

As pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454547/matlab-plot-a-cosine-wave/60456627#comment106950638_60454547) by @[Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2732801/daniel), you can also make the plot with [`nlintool()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlintool.html) but this **requires the Statistics Toolbox**.

```
nlintool(Xdata,Ydata,cos_fun,[1 1 0])         % toolbox required
```

[image: Plot comparing fitted functions to the data. No toolbox required.]

---

## Fitting

**Using [`nlinfit()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html):**    (Statistics Toolbox Required)

```
pNL = nlinfit(Xdata,Ydata,cos_fun,[1 1 0])       % same as SSE approach below
```

**A Toolbox Free Approach:**
You can construct a convex error function to minimize and return the global optimum using [`fminsearch()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) as a down and dirty approach. For example, the sum of squared error or the sum of absolute error will be [convex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function).

```
% MATLAB R2019a
% Generate Example Data
sigma = 0.5;                   % increase this for more variable data (more noise)
Xdata = [repmat(1:10,1,4)].';
Ydata = cos(Xdata)+sigma*randn(length(Xdata),1);

% Function Evaluation
cos_fun=@(p,x) p(1) + p(2).*cos(x-p(3));

% Error Functions
SSEh =@(p) sum((cos_fun(p,Xdata)-Ydata).^2);   % sum of squared error
SAEh =@(p) sum(abs(cos_fun(p,Xdata)-Ydata));   % sum of absolute error
```

Of course, these will give you different errors for the same parameter.

```
% Test
SSEh([1 1 0])
SAEh([1 1 0])
```

But you then call `fminsearch()` given an initial guess for the parameters, `p0`, to obtain the parameters that minimize your chosen error function.  Since `SSEh` and `SAEh` are both convex with respect to `p`, there's no need to do this multiple times and save the best one since for every `p0`, you'll get the same answer.

```
p0 = [1 1 0.25];     % Initial starting point
[p_SSE, SSE] = fminsearch(SSEh,p0)             
[p_SAE, SAE] = fminsearch(SAEh,p0)
```

You fit slightly different curves depending on the error function.

Notice that `SSEh(pNL)` and `SSEh(p_SSE)` are the same since `pNL` equals `p_SSE` since [`nlinfit()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) estimates the coefficients "using iterative least squares estimation."